# JavaScript extract data from variable / array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have what I assume is an array in JavaScript that looks like this when I echo it to the console log using console.log(data.position);

```
c.Point {left: 98, right: 34, tmode: 15}
```

I am trying to get the values for left and right so I can use them elsewhere in the script. What can I try?

Comment: Console formatting does not translate well to actual code. Can you change that to `console.log(JSON.stringify(data.position, null, '  '))`? Also, what have you tried and what result do you get?

Comment: That is a simple Javascript object - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp.

Access the values by using `data.position.left` and `data.position.right`

Comment: `var left = data.position.left, right = data.position.right;` and then `console.log("position: ", left, right);`

Comment: its an object. use ``c.Point["left"]`` to get the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console formatting of your object simply states that the object you're logging (`data.position`) is of class `c.Point`, with properties `left`, `right` and `tmode`.

To access these properties, just do it as if it's any other JavaScript object:

```js
var left = data.position.left;
var right = data.position.right;

// example: do something with left and right
console.log(left, right);                              // prints '98 34'
```

or

```js
// example: do something with data.position.left and data.position.right directly
console.log(data.position.left, data.position.right);  // prints '98 34'
```

Answer (score -1):

Es6 way using object.keys you can do this very easily

```
    var boo ={left: 98, right: 34, tmode: 15};
    var keys = Object.keys(boo); 

    console.log(keys);
    //["left", "right", "tmode"]0: "left"1: "right"2: "tmode"length: 3__proto__: Array[0]
    // now for getting specific keys using there index
    let leftKey = keys[0];
    let rightKey = keys[1];
    console.log(leftKey); //get left key 
    console.log(rightKey); //get right key
```

Now in order to get the value of those keys do this,

```
console.log(boo[leftKey]); //98
console.log(boo[rightKey]) // 34
```

But as everyone mentioned that data.position is returning the object so, i  believe you can access the value using data.position.KEYNAME

Comment: This is not correct. The question asks for the values of `left` and `right`, not the keys themselves. Regardless, the order of keys of [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is arbitrary, so your code won't always give the indended result.